# How to find indices with a negative value and replace the value with the nearest index's value that happens to be positive?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision, interpolation

I know how to find indices with a negative value from a matrix.

```
matrix(matrix<0) = %something should be done;
```

But don't know how to replace their values with the nearest index's value that happens to be positive.

1. The nearest index here should be in the same row where the observed index is laid.
2. If there is no index with a positive value in the row, 0 should be interpolated to every index of that row.
3. If there is more than one index that is the nearest to the observed index in the same row, choose the right one.
4. I am dealing with 1003x1170 single matrix. So it would be best if the solution doesn't come with so much overhead.

For example,

```
[-255  4  6; 
   -5 -4  5; 
 -400  3  6; 
   -6 -7 -8;
    3 -5  4]
```

Becomes

```
[4 4 6; 
 5 5 5; 
 3 3 6;
 0 0 0;
 3 4 4]
```

Comment: The correct procedure is to edit the closed question so it can be reopened. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737900/how-to-find-indices-with-a-negative-value-and-replace-the-value-with-the-nearest

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize it was a _different_ question. Anyway, for this time it's probably better to delete the old one, now that the new one has an answer. But for the future, @mrki102, please do it as Cris says

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using the [`fillmissing`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html) function, as follows:

1. Replace negative values by `NaN`. This is needed because, for `single` or `double` input, `fillmissing` considers `NaN` entries as missing values.
2. Use `fillmissing` with the `'nearest'` option and operating along dimension `2`. If there are two equidistant data values, `fillmissing` *apparently* chooses the one to the right (I haven't found this documented, and I haven't been able to confirm it from the source code).
3. Replace any remaining `NaN` values (corresponding to rows that didn't contain non-negative values) by `0`.

```
matrix = [-255 4 6; -5 -4  5; -400 3 6; -6 -7 -8; 3 -5 4];  % data
matrix(matrix<0) = NaN;                                     % step 1
matrix = fillmissing(matrix, 'nearest', 2);                 % step 2
matrix(isnan(matrix)) = 0;                                  % step 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It works well! BTW what if one wants to interpolate with the nearest non-negative index's value throughout the matrix and not with the nearest one on the same row?

Comment: I've tried it. The default value of the third argument is '1' and it means the nearest non-NaN index's value on the same column.

Comment: @mrki102 Ah, sorry (deleting comment to avoid confusion to future readers). Actually that behaviour makes more sense than the one I assumed, as many functions do that: default to the first non-singleton dimension. So perhaps [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) can be of help. If you are interested, that would probably require a new question (be sure to explain the difference with this one), as it is a quite different problem

Comment: I opened the new question for this one :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753924/replacing-indices-with-an-unwanted-value-with-their-the-nearest-indexs-value-th

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

- Iterate columns from right to left.
- Replace each negative value in the column with the value to the right.
- Make sure that the most right column (one past matrix bounds) is initialized with zeros.

Code sample:

```
A = [  -255     4     6
         -5    -4     5
       -400     3     6
         -6    -7    -8
          3    -5     4];

[rows, cols] = size(A);

P = zeros(rows, 1); %Column to the right of c initialize to zeros (like padding right side of A with zeros column).

%Loop over columns from right to left
for c = cols:-1:1
    if c < cols
        P = A(:, c+1); %Column to the right of c - assumed to be all positive (or zeros).
    end

    C = A(:, c); %Column c.
    C(C < 0) = P(C < 0); %Replace negative elements with elements from right column (all elements in P are positive or zeros).
    A(:, c) = C; %Replace column in C
end
```

---

Result:

```
A =

     4     4     6
     5     5     5
     3     3     6
     0     0     0
     3     4     4
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It works well! BTW what if one wants to interpolate with the nearest non-negative index's value throughout the matrix and not with the nearest one on the same row?

Comment: It makes things more complicated... I can't think of any elegant solution.