# Replacing indices with an unwanted value with their the nearest index's value that happens to be positive

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision, interpolation

This question is different from the previous question ([How to find indices with a negative value and replace the value with the nearest index's value that happens to be positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742108/how-to-find-indices-with-a-negative-value-and-replace-the-value-with-the-nearest)).
The previous question was to replace an index's unwanted value with its nearest positive index's value **on the same row**.

This question is to replace the unwanted value with its nearest positive index's value **throughout the entire matrix (not only limited to the same row)**.

- If there is more than one index that is the nearest to the observed index in the entire matrix, take the value randomly (it doesn't really matter tbh).
- I am dealing with a 1003x1170 single matrix. So it would be best if the solution doesn't come with so much overhead. (optional)

For example, if the negative values are unwanted,

```
[-255  4  6;
   -5 -4  5;
 -400  3  6;
   -6 -7 -8;
    3 -5  4]
```

becomes

```
[4 4 6;
 4 5 5;
 3 3 6;
 3 3 6;
 3 4 4]
```

(The answer doesn't necessarily have to be like this since it takes the nearest value randomly (right/left/up/down whatever, if it makes things easier by adding some consistency, that is also fine.))

*Purpose: I am trying to do this to remove the big size of the noise holes in the observed image matrix without killing the sharpness of the image.*

Thank you for your supports!

Comment: Consider a 3*3 kernel (like when you do a image filtering) and for each negative pixel, search in the 3*3 neighborhood and select the first positive value. If you didn't find positive value, consider a 5*5 neighborhood for that special pixel, and so on try bigger kernels until you find a positive value. This may not be the fastest algorithm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code replaces each negative number by the nearest non-negative number. If there are several non-negative numbers at the same minimum distance, the *first one in linear order* is used.

### Without loop

This builds a very large matrix as intermediate result. It may not work for large inputs due to memory limitations.

```
matrix = [-255 4 6; -5 -4 5; -400 3 16; -6 -7 -8; 13 -5  14];
[r_use, c_use] = find(matrix>=0); % row and column indices of useful values
z_use = r_use+1j*c_use; % same as complex number
[r_neg, c_neg] = find(matrix<0); % row and column indices of negative values
z_neg = r_neg+1j*c_neg; % same as complex number
[~, ind_min] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, z_use, z_neg.')), [], 1); % compute distance
    % between each useful value and each negative value. For each negative value, 
    % give  index of nearest useful value. This index is referred to r_use, c_use
ind_use = sub2ind(size(matrix), r_use(ind_min), c_use(ind_min)); % linear indices 
    % of useful values that will replace the negative values
ind_neg = sub2ind(size(matrix), r_neg, c_neg); % linear indices of negative values
matrix(ind_neg) = matrix(ind_use); % replace
```

Before:

```
matrix =
  -255     4     6
    -5    -4     5
  -400     3    16
    -6    -7    -8
    13    -5    14
```

After:

```
matrix =
     4     4     6
     4     4     5
     3     3    16
    13     3    16
    13    13    14
```

### With loop

This reduces memory consumption by working with the negative values one at a time, using a loop.

```
matrix = [-255 4 6; -5 -4 5; -400 3 16; -6 -7 -8; 13 -5  14];
[r_use, c_use] = find(matrix>=0); % row and column indices of useful values
z_use = r_use+1j*c_use; % same as complex number
[r_neg, c_neg] = find(matrix<0); % row and column indices of negative values
z_neg = r_neg+1j*c_neg; % same as complex number
for k = 1:numel(z_neg) % for each negative value
    [~, ind_min_k] = min(abs(z_use-z_neg(k))); % compute distance between
    % each useful value and this negative value. Give index of nearest
    % useful value. This index is referred to r_use, c_use
    ind_use_k = sub2ind(size(matrix), r_use(ind_min_k), c_use(ind_min_k));
    % linear index of useful value that will replace this negative value
    ind_neg_k = sub2ind(size(matrix), r_neg(k), c_neg(k)); % linear index
    % of this negative value
    matrix(ind_neg_k) = matrix(ind_use_k); % replace
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But I got this error.
Error using bsxfun

``Requested 1056909x116601 (1836.4GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause
MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.``

I guess my matrix is way too big to compute this...

Comment: Yes, I hadn't thought of that. You need a loop then. You can loop over each negative value and do as my code does for each of them (but no need for `bsxfun` now). Let me know if you need help and I will edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I need the edited version of the code for the bigger matrix!

Comment: @mrki102 Edited

Comment: I tried the one with loop, its been more than 3 minutes and still, the output hasn't come. I have a feeling that I'm stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Well, your matrix is large, and loops are usually slower (sometimes much slower) than vectorized code. You can add something like `disp(round(k/numel(z_neg)*100))` after the `for` line to see progress in percentage

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for your help:^)

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use the second output of [`bwdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) to find the nearest positive index value.

```
matrix = [-255  4  6;
          -5   -4  5;
          -400  3  6;
          -6   -7 -8;
           3   -5  4];
bw = matrix >= 0;
[~, idx] = bwdist(bw);

result = matrix;
result(~bw) = result(idx(~bw));
```

The result will be:

```
result =
   4   4   6
   3   4   5
   3   3   6
   3   3   6
   3   3   4
```

Here the result is computed based on *euclidean* distance. You can use `bwdist` with other distance metrics to produce different results.